# MySQL database design: one-to-many relationship with two parents and one child

Tags: mysql, database-design

What is the proper design for the following situation:

I have people (t_people) who have phone numbers (t_numbers).

Looks like a simple one to many relationship with a foreign key in the numbers table.
[EER diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9bnD.png)

But not only people can have phone numbers - companies (t_companies) can have phone numbers too.

I want to use only one phone number table. It looks like I need two one-to-many relationsships with one table (t_numbers) refering to either the t_people OR to t_companies.

Should I use two foreign keys allowing both of them to be NULL.
[EER diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18pCb.png)

Or should I simply not use foreign keys at all?
E.g. I could have one "reference column" with the ID of EITHER one or the other table and a second one in which the table is stored to which the first column refers to.
[I am not allowed to post a third image ...]

How is such a problem usually solved?

(Or shoudl I just give up my plan of having just ONE phone number table and make one for people and one for comapnies.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your should stick with your first diagram and simply add a type (person or company)  column to the t_people table (may be renaming the table to something more generic).

If you want it normalized (and you will) It should be a good idea to create the entity type table with at least 2 rows  (person and company) and relate this table with the "t_people"

Comment: Do you suggest putting people and companies in the same table and just differentiate them with a property? An rename them to - let's say t_thingsintheworldwhichcouldhavephonenumbers? t_peoples will contain totally different fields then the company table.

Answer (score 0):

Can two members of the same family have the same phone number?  Can a person list his company phone?

But...

Let's not design the schema until we have a good picture of what `SELECTs`, etc, are needed.

If you only need to display "all phone numbers for a given entity", then a `VARCHAR` could have a commalist of numbers.

If you need to answer "who/what does this number belong to", then you need to focus on a table of phone numbers as the dominant table.  It *could* have multiple rows for the same phone number.  Or there could be a many-to-many table (or more than one such) to map phone numbers to entities.

Or maybe "Entity" is the focus.  And Entity could be a Person or a Company.  That smells like 3 tables -- Entity, Person, and Company.

Postpone thinking about the FOREIGN KEYS; get the logic right first, then the FKs will fall into place.